# Accessing multiple models through one controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-4

Sorry for the Noob question. I have a form that allows a user to create a resume. I created a Resume scaffold with inputs for title and career objective. I made separate database tables for the other sections (experience, education, skills). I want to have all of this information submitted using one single form being the `resumes/views/_form.html` with the resume controller. So in the Resume Model I put ( `has_many :experiences` ) and in the Experience Model I put ( `belongs_to :resume` ). My Experience table has two fields (`:job_title`, `:job_description`), so in the `views/resumes/_form.html` I added two additional fields for `:job_title` and `:job_description`. I'm kind of lost at this point. How do I save those input values to the appropriate database tables using the Resume controllers 'new' and 'create' methods? I know I'm missing code right now, but I'm getting this error if it's any help:

```
undefined method `job_title' for #<Resume:0x007fe5b2304748>

Trace of template inclusion: app/views/resumes/new.html.erb

app/views/resumes/_form.html.erb:24:in `block in _app_views_resumes__form_html_erb___303730996527532694_70312260165660'
app/views/resumes/_form.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_resumes__form_html_erb___303730996527532694_70312260165660'
app/views/resumes/new.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_resumes_new_html_erb___2010250825676564736_70312281682320'
```

Here is the /resumes/_form.html.erb view

```
    <%= form_for(@resume) do |f| %>
  <% if @resume.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@resume.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this resume from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @resume.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :objective %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :objective %>
  </div>
  <%= fields_for @experience do |fa| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= fa.label :job_title %><br>
      <%= fa.text_area :job_title %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= fa.label :company_name %><br>
      <%= fa.text_area :company_name %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The resumes_controller

```
class ResumesController < ApplicationController
      before_action :set_resume, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

      # GET /resumes
      # GET /resumes.json
      def index
        @resumes = Resume.all
      end

      # GET /resumes/1
      # GET /resumes/1.json
      def show
      end

      # GET /resumes/new
      def new
        @resume = Resume.new
      end

      # GET /resumes/1/edit
      def edit
      end

      # POST /resumes
      # POST /resumes.json
      def create
        @resume = Resume.new(resume_params)

        respond_to do |format|
          if @resume.save
            format.html { redirect_to @resume, notice: 'Resume was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @resume }
          else
            format.html { render action: 'new' }
            format.json { render json: @resume.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end

      # PATCH/PUT /resumes/1
      # PATCH/PUT /resumes/1.json
      def update
        respond_to do |format|
          if @resume.update(resume_params)
            format.html { redirect_to @resume, notice: 'Resume was successfully updated.' }
            format.json { head :no_content }
          else
            format.html { render action: 'edit' }
            format.json { render json: @resume.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end

      # DELETE /resumes/1
      # DELETE /resumes/1.json
      def destroy
        @resume.destroy
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to resumes_url }
          format.json { head :no_content }
        end
      end

      private
        # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
        def set_resume
          @resume = Resume.find(params[:id])
        end

        # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
        def resume_params
          params.require(:resume).permit(:title, :objective)
        end
    end
```

Comment: Add `resumes/views/_form.html` code.

Comment: Need a little bit more detail to go more into depth. But the basic Gist is that you have to use the controller to store the data in the different models.

Comment: @RAJ... - Added the _form.html view. If you need the controller view or anything just let me know. Thanks for the help, truly appreciate it!

Comment: @SankalpSingha I added the resumes/view/_form.html if that helps. If the controller would help as well I can post that. I really appreciate the help!

Comment: Yes, show the controller, so we can tell you how to modify it to spread your posted data around to the various models.

Comment: @Daiku Added the resumes_controller. Thank you! Really appreciate any help.

Comment: Did you try what I suggested in my answer?  If you post your models, I can show you how to set `up accepts_nested_attributes_for`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to change

```
<%= fields_for @experience do |fa| %>
```

to

```
<%= f.fields_for @experience do |fa| %>
```

And make sure you have `accepts_nested_attributes_for` set up correctly in the models.